# Access View from Another Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm using a ListView with custom list items (including a button). I have a custom adapter, in which I set the button's OnClickListener to an inner class (defined in the adapter class).

I want to access the button in the class (defined in a different xml file from the ListAcitivty class's) in which the listview is displayed. I want to set it's onClickListener method inside this class. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Edit:
   This is my list_item.xml (I use for my ListView rows).

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:contentDescription="Color"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp" 
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    >
</EditText>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/deleleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/delete_button" >

</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I access the button (id:deleteButton) inside my class that extends ListActivity? The class that extends listactivity has a separate layout (main.xml let's say). If I do setContentView(main) inside the class that extends listactivity, findViewById(R.id.deleteButton) would return null.

Edit 2:
This is my class that extends ListActivity. If I place findViewById(R.id.deleteButton) after the setContentView it returns null.

```
public class PlayerSelection extends ListActivity {
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<PlayerField> textviews = null;
    PlayerFieldsAdapter adapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_selection_page);
        list = getListView();

        textviews = new ArrayList<PlayerField>();
        for (int i = 0; i< GlobalVariables.getPlayers(); i++) {
            textviews.add(i, new PlayerField());
        }
        adapter = new PlayerFieldsAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, textviews); 

    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
    Button backButton = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < header.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = header.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof Button) {
            backButton = (Button) v;
            break;
        }
    }
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent optionsIntent = new Intent(PlayerSelection.this, OptionsScreen.class);
                startActivity(optionsIntent);
            }
        });
    list.addHeaderView(header);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: You should consider posting some code cause it's hard to understand the problem.

Comment: I added code, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I meant Java code actually, not XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to achieve this is to create a field inside your `CustomAdapter` class:

```
private OnClickListener listener;
```

Then specify a setter method for this field. Next step will be to specify this listener inside your `Activity` class like that:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) getListView().getAdapter();
adapter.setListener(<your implementation of the listener>);
```

Then inside your `CustomAdapter`'s `getView()` method you set this listener to your button:

```
Button btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to ask @Egor that What to Write in place of "<your implementation of the listener>"

Comment: @NiravDabhi, OnClickListener is an interface, and there are multiple ways to implement an interface. The easiest way is to pass an anonymous class implementing OnClickListener, or make ListActivity implement OnClickListener and pass the "this" reference.

Comment: You meant to say should I do like this "adapter.setListener(this);"

Comment: @NiravDabhi, Yes, this will work if your Activity implements OnClickListener.