# Trying to setOnClickListener for TextView not in main layout

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView that I am turning into a button.  The TextView actually lives on a secondary layout.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);
```

this is the main layout here "R.layout.history"

That loads a bunch of results in a ListAdapter and each result is displayed using R.layout.card_background

I am trying to initialize and set the setOnClickListener for a TextView located on R.Layout.card_background but I am getting a nullPointerException.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Roboto-Light.ttf");

        ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        TextView history = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.history);
        history.setTypeface(tf);




        Cursor cursor = db.getAllLogs();
        Log.d("history.java", "finished Cursor cursor = db.getAllLogs();");
        String[] from = {"_id", "dd", "gg", "ppg", "odo"};
        int[] to = {deleteVal, R.id.cardDate, R.id.cardG, R.id.cardP, R.id.cardM};
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.card_background, cursor, from, to);
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);

        TextView cardDelete = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cardDelete);
        cardDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

            }
        });
    }
```

Any idea how I can set that and stop getting the NPE?

Thanks

Comment: You're getting the nullpointer exception because that editText doesn't exist in the current view, so you can add any listener to nothing.

Comment: check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381885/access-view-from-another-layout)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a custom Adapter that extends SimpleCursorAdapter and add the `OnClickListener` in the `getView()` method.

As you try it now, the TextView is searched in the activity layout, not found of course, thus the variable does not get filled, and the app crashes as soon as you want to perform a method on a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

i believe that your activity is bind to another contentView which is `setContentView(R.layout.history);`hence the nullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually did a little more digging and tried this.  If someone can tell me why this is a bad/good idea though I would appreciate it as I'd rather not commit it to memory if it is going to be harmful to the application.

```
final LayoutInflater cardLayout = getLayoutInflater();
        final View cardDeleteText = cardLayout.inflate(R.layout.card_background,  null);
        TextView cardDelete = (TextView) cardDeleteText.findViewById(R.id.cardDelete);
        cardDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can inflate a custom layout from card_background

use this code

```
View card_background_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_background, container, false);
```

then 
replace this

```
TextView history = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.history);
```

with this

```
TextView history =(TextView)card_background_view.findViewById(R.id.history);
```